# Replacing ,(comma) with line break <br> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code to get selected values from multiple select and displaying these values in a textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#client").change(function(){
   var sel = $("#client").val();
          $("#clientselected").text(sel);
     });
});
```

Selected values are separated by comma, now I want each selected value in each line in textarea. I tried replacing `,` with `<br>` using `replace` function, but I was unable to. How can I do this?

Comment: what would be the value in that variable sel..?

Comment: Change `.text` to `.html`.

Comment: @PandiyanCool - Not even the same.

Comment: `var sel = $("#client").val(); sel.replace(',','<br>');          $("#clientselected").html(sel);` if it's as straight forward as the OP makes it seem.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 .html is just removing commas and printing continuosly

Comment: @user3549665 - I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I think Arun got it correct. OP states he grabs the values from a multiple select.

Comment: Hi i also have an answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/23355741/1109352 by using append and newline (\n) instead of text() and <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you have a multiple select, `.val()` will return an array of option values so you can use `.join()` to with `\n` as the seperator
- You need use `.val()` to set the value to the `clientselected` element

So

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#client").change(function () {
        var sel = $("#client").val();
        $("#clientselected").val(sel.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TVECV/)

Comment: I have copy pasted above code. I am getting output as value1<br />value2<br > value3    Fiddle is working. What is the problem with?

Comment: @user3549665 updated now... I forgot about the point you made about textarea

Comment: why join? you are just getting it from a single combobox

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks in a `<textarea>` element are made with `\n` not html breaks. You should also set the value.

```
$("textarea").val("a line\nand another\nandanother");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want to replace the `<br/>` with `\n`, if it's in a text area (which won't know what to do with HTML tags, in general.

http://jsfiddle.net/KYMUc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use newline ("\n") or "`&#13;`" instead of 
 to make a line break

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#client").change(function () {
        var sel = $("#client").val();
        $("#clientselected").html(sel.join("\n") + "\n");
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremejazz/LZqC2/)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#clientselected").html(sel.split(",").join("\n"));
```

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/101/)</kbd>

Comment: Because all the answers were wrong...Amazing how they all change when me and one other person posted the correct line break...

Comment: explain the reason @epascarello

Comment: Dude you had <br> and I downvoted...Can't hide it with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/100/